# Failed to start Bitcoin daemon

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, tor, bitcoin.conf

I set up Tor with bitcoind. After that, when I started the daemon, I got the following error.

Error: Cannot set -bind or -whitebind together with -listen=0

My bitcoin.conf is:

```
server=1
txindex=1
daemon=1
listen=1
rpcport=8332
rpcbind=0.0.0.0
rpcallowip=127.0.0.1
rpcallowip=10.0.0.0/8
rpcallowip=172.0.0.0/8
rpcallowip=192.0.0.0/8
whitelist=127.0.0.1
proxy=127.0.0.1:9050
bind=127.0.0.1
onlynet=onion
```

It starts when I remove bind from bitcoin.conf.
On ubuntu

Anyone have any tips?
thank you.

Comment: Are you sure your bitcoin.conf includes `listen=1`, because the error message suggests you're setting `listen=0`?

Comment: Yes.It’s including.The problem is that I get a listen=0 error even though I have listen=1 set.

Comment: Are passing `-listen=0` on the command line perhaps? It must be coming from somewhere.

Comment: Doesn't `-proxy` disable `-listen`? EDIT: Just checked, it does. Writing an answer.

Comment: I was able to connect with Onion.
It seems there was a problem with the settings in bitcoin-qt (probably).
However, I am concerned about whether the incoming connection is going well. Because bitcoin-qt is incoming, but network test on 'bitnodes.io' gives 'unreachable' result. is this a problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've set incompatible options. `bind=1` requires `listen=1` but `proxy=X.X.X.X` overwrites `listen` to `0`.

Comment: I will check if there is a problem with the proxy settings.